# PhpStorm suggestions of dynamic class declaration

Tags: php, class, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm, and I have a class like this.

```
class MasterClass {
    public function getClass($className)
    {
        require_once("/php/class/$className.php");
        $newClass = new $className();
        return $newClass;
    }
}
```

And I call this method in my PHP file like this.

```
$MasterClass = new MasterClass();
$roles = $MasterClass->getClass('Roles');
$roles->
```

But of course, my IDE cannot show suggestions/function usage with this solution.

Is it possible to show suggestions using something like PHPDoc? I found a solution for the function usage using `@see classname::method()`, but I have to do it for all the methods I called.

I tried with

```
/** @link Roles */
$roles = $MasterClass->getClass('Roles');
```

as well as

```
/** @see Roles */
$roles = $MasterClass->getClass('Roles');
```

Comment: You could use PHPDoc to provide hints to your IDE about the type of object being returned. In your case, you can use the @return tag.

Comment: @KarlHill I tried this ` /**
     * @param $className
     * @return $className
     */
    public function getClass($className)
    { ` but with $className it doesn't work..

Comment: *"I tried with"* -- just use the correct tag -- it's `@var` -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#518-var In your case it would be something like `/** @var \Roles $roles */` (use FQN if class is not in `use` list).

Comment: Alternatively you can typehint `getClass()` method (but it may not always work). It has to be done with PhpStorm specific Advanced Metadata functionality -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#override

Comment: @LazyOne yes, it works with metadata too! It's faster because I don't have to add a comment everytime I call the function..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LazyOne, the solution is to write a file called ".phpstorm.meta.php" in project folder and to write inside this

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(\MasterClass::getClass(), map([
        'special' => '@Class'
    ]));
}
```

Comment: Just to clearify `'special' => '@Class'` tells the IDE that the return type of `getClass('special')` call will be `specialClass`. I guess the correct one for a simple pattern matching would be `'' => '@'` (not using this functionality myself and therefore cannot test it properly) or hardcoding all actual classes, i.e. `'Roles' => '\Roles'` and so on). Well, whatever you have actually there -- as long as it works correctly for you.